# Custom Comparator in Template for sorting

Tags: c++, templates

One sentence of background; I'm a uni student and am in the last week of "Advanced C++" and that's my skill level (whatever that means). So here is the deal. This is the definitions for my my SkipList Class. It stores data by sorting 'K' (the key) and hold the data type 'V' (value and can be anything but for this just assume int).

My issue is I don't know how to implement the Comparator with a template. Or really anything with the comparator. I also have the SkipNode defined (not shown) and that works, but should I have the comparator template in the Node if its never needed?

I know for a fact that what I have here is correct (as given to my by the Prof). How do I (in my `int main()`) construct the skip_list? How do I use the Comp in my `insert()` fn? Because right now it's just hard coded as a `<`.

I know how hard it can be to answer these slightly more advanced questions without further knowledge of the project, so thank you in advance with the help. Please let me know if there is anything more I can show you.

```
template <typename K, typename V, typename Comp = std::less<K> >
class Skip_list {
public:
  Skip_list<K, V, Comp> (const Comp& c = Comp());
  ~Skip_list<K, V, Comp> ();

  // NON-MODIFYING MEMBER FUNCTIONS
  void print ();
  SkipNode<K, V, Comp>* find (K searchKey);

  // MODIFYING MEMBER FUNCTIONS
  void insert (K searchKey, V newValue);
  void erase (K searchKey);
private:
  // POINTER TO FIRST NODE
  SkipNode<K, V, Comp>* head;
  // POINTER TO LAST NODE
  SkipNode<K, V, Comp>* NIL;

  // IMPLICITLY USED MEMBER FUNCTIONS
  int randomLevel ();
  int nodeLevel(const std::vector<SkipNode<K, V, Comp>* >& v);
  SkipNode<K, V, Comp>* makeNode (K key, V val, int level);

  // DATA MEMBERS
  float probability;
  int maxLevel;
};
```

/* WHOLE BUNCH O'CODE */

```
template <typename K, typename V, typename Comp >
void Skip_list<K, V, Comp>::insert(K searchKey, V newValue) {
    // REASSIGN IF NODE EXISTS
    SkipNode<K, V, Comp>* x = nullptr;
    x = find(searchKey);
    if (x) {
        x->value_ = newValue;
        return;
    }

    // VECTOR OF POINTERS THAT NEEDS TO BE UPDATED TO ACCOUNT FOR THE NEW NODE
    std::vector<SkipNode<K, V, Comp>* > update(head->forward_);
    int currentMaximum = nodeLevel(head->forward_);
    x = head;

    // SEARCH THE LIST
    for (int i = currentMaximum; i-- > 0;) {

        while (x->forward_[i] != nullptr && x->forward_[i]->key_ < searchKey) {

            x = x->forward_[i];
        }
        update[i] = x;
    }
    x = x->forward_[0];

    // CREATE NEW NODE
    int newNodeLevel = 1;
    if (x->key_ != searchKey) {

        newNodeLevel = randomLevel();
        int currentLevel = nodeLevel(update);

        if (newNodeLevel > currentLevel) {

            for (int i = currentLevel + 1; i < newNodeLevel; ++i) {

                update[i] = head;
            }
        }
        x = makeNode(searchKey, newValue, newNodeLevel);
    }

    // CONNECT POINTERS OF PREDECESSEORS AND NEW NODE TO SUCCESSORS
    for (int i = 0; i < newNodeLevel; ++i) {

        x->forward_[i] = update[i]->forward_[i];
        update[i]->forward_[i] = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps show us the body of the `insert` function where you wish to use the comparator?

Comment: The 'while' loop inside the "Search" block, is what needs to use that Comp. specifically 'x->forward_[i]->key_ < searchKey' and this is where I run through the list and find where to insert the new node.

Comment: I suggest reading up on functors (your template parameter `Comp`). A functor basically is a class for which `operator()` is overloaded. Instead of using `operator <` you'd create an instance of `Comp` and call that object like a function. You need a member of type `Comp` as you have a constructor to initialize Comp at runtime.